# Is it sense of lying if ticking the checkbox of software terms/condition without reading it?

Tags: halal-haram, software, lying

There are mostly software and applications for mobiles and laptops that asked users to accept the terms and conditions before using the app. Many people continue without reading that terms because these are usually very long texts and paragraphs. If there's the title for checkbox of terms/conditions is **I have read and accept the terms and conditions** and user tick it without reading it. Then it is a sense of lying and haram the use of that software?

Answer (score 1):

in a sense of you asking, mostly not, if you are aware not to do harmful things etc. as long s you are aware about them, then in a way no its not a sense of lying or haram

Comment: It makes some sense but what if i'm new to that software and don't know what are possible terms? And without reading i tick the checkbox to continue.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not. Especially given the length and complexity of these terms and conditions.

It's basically the collective responsibility of watchdogs and regulatory agencies to make sure that software companies don't abuse the trust that's given them - it's not simply the individual's responsibility, though of course that matters.

People generally click through on them as they trust that watchdogs and regulatory bodies do a good enough job so that they don't have to worry too much about the terms and conditions, except in unusual circumstances.

So no, it's not lying. If anything, it's sensible.